# Qt changing the background color of QWidget using palette doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the background color in a custom subclass of QWidget.
Here is the code:

```
WorldView::WorldView(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QPalette p(palette());
    p.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::black);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setPalette(p);
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. The background color remains unchanged.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html), `QPalette::Background` is obsolete. Use `QPalette::Window` instead. Note that some widgets use some other role for the background. See the [QPalette::ColorRole documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum)

Also:

> Warning: Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for
>   instance, if they make use of native theme engines. This is the case
>   for both the Windows XP, Windows Vista, and the OS X styles.

In this case I suggest to use style sheets. See [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

However, if WorldView is a custom widget, with your custom `paintEvent`, it's up to you to draw the background

Comment: I have tried to change `Background` into `Window`, but it still doesn't work. (As the document says, `Background` is defined as `Window`.) Maybe the problem lies on an other place. Still thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have to set `autoFillBackground` to true (`QWidget::setAutoFillBackground(bool)`)

Answer (score 4):

Use `QPalette::Base` instead of `QPalette::Background`

```
 QPalette p(palette());
 p.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::lightGray);
 setPalette(p);
```

For some reason custom widget uses `QPalette::Base` for filling backgound

Answer (score 1):

```
setStyleSheet('background-color:black;')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the palette color doesnt work then it can have four reasons you should check

- you have set the colors from style sheets which i don't recommend at all or maybe you have set the parents stylesheet
- your color role in the palette doesnt match
- make sure the palette is set for widget and i dont recommend to set palette for every widget unless you really wanted to, you should set the palette for your application
- or maybe your window manager is forcing colors and palettes dont work at all

Thats all i got in my mind, if you know more, please edit this answere and add it to items